# JavaScript Null does not convert to None

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

```
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser, FormParser])
@api_view(['POST', ])
def product_list(request):
    print(request.POST.get('key'))
    print(request.data.get('key'))
    print(request.FILES)
```

When I am sending form data with value of key=null it displays null as string but didn't convert to None what should I do. The work around that I have to do
is something like

```
if request.data.get('key', None) in ['null', None]:
    #then do something
```

But this doesn't seem to be a clean way of doing this. So what should I do?

I expected that django or django rest framework will automatically convert null to None.

Comment: Probably your `request.data` is a JSON object. And JSON does not know the Python specific `None`, but instead stores `null`. You can try to load the JSON object to a `dict`, which will convert `null` to `None`

Comment: @AnsFourtyTwo `request.data` is just the parsed entity body (it's a superset of the POST data), there's no JSON involved until the author shoves JSON values into their POST data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as null/none in HTTP form-data content (in fact there's no such thing as types in the way we'd usually understand, though there can be a content-type associated with each item).

So what happens here is on the *javascript* side the `null` gets converted to a string, added to the data, sent to the server, which just gets a `null` string without any more information.

Generally, "null" items would be missing entirely, alternatively, they would have an empty value associated with them.

Either way, this is not an issue with django.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small workaround to solve this issue by designing a middleware. I dont know if its good but it worked for me. I made it first mutable, changed it then made immutable again.

#### Note : if data sent is nested json you have to alter it to handle json recursively.

```
from django import http
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class NullStringToNoneMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    """Responsible for converting all string null values to None"""
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.POST._mutable = True
        for j in request.POST:
            if request.POST[j] == 'null':
                request.POST[j] = None
        request.POST._mutable = False
```